# Write a float array to a CSV file

Tags: python, arrays, csv

I have a float array (created by: `array('f')`) and I want to write its contents as a 1-column CSV file, that is, each element of the array will take one line of the resulting file.

```
from array import array

my_array = array('f')
with open(filename, 'w') as output:
    my_array = populate_method()
    writer = csv.writer(output)
    print(my_array)  # verifying that the data exist
    writer.writerows(my_array.tolist())
```

I get this error at the latest line: `_csv.Error: sequence expected`.
What is wrong? Isn't the list a sequence?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

why ... you can just write it

```
with open("outfile","wb") as f:
     f.write("\n".join(str(x) for x in my_list))
```

the problem with your original code is that writerows expects a 2d list and you are just giving it a one dimensional list, therfor 
alternatively you can convert your 1d list into a 1column 2d list with

```
my_list_i_can_use_with_writerows = zip(*[myList])
```

Comment: Writing it directly was my first attempt, but didn't came up with the "\n".join syntax and so all the elements were in one line. Some follow-up questions: 1. Why does write_rows expect a 2D list? 2. Could you elaborate on the syntax of `zip(*[myList])` ?